# DBPedia Identifying URIs

Tags: dbpedia

Currently I'm using the dbpedia ontology [ontology](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.7/dbpedia_3.7.owl.bz2/)
to identify the type hierarchy  [mapping based properties](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.7/en/mappingbased_properties_en.nt.bz2) to extract attributes from the entities and to identify relationships between them. To identify the type of an entity i use the dataset [infobox types / instance types](http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.7/en/instance_types_en.nt.bz2) Using the java.net.URlDecoder for identifying an entity's name I get a lot of not found errors in the batch chain i build. Is there anything I'm doing wrong on a conceptual level? (Basically it works but some entities can't be resolved to a type defaulting in unknown). Do I need to use any additional datasets for identiying dbpedia types?

Update for clarity: I'm using the type instances like this:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Disease> .
```

I'm extracting Autism and Disease to establish that Autism is a disease. To map the attributes to autism I'm using:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/diseasesdb> "1142"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/icd9> "299.00"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/omim> "209850"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/medlineplus> "001526"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/emedicineSubject> "med"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/emedicineTopic> "3202"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/meshId> "D001321"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name> "Autism"@en .
```

If the last statement in the triple is not an attribute  I'm creating a  relationship between those elements.  What should I do to identify an URI?

```
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism>
```

Just stripping off the tags and extracting the word Autism doesn't seem to to the deal?

Comment: You'll need to give some more detail, I think. It's not clear what you mean by "Using the java.net.URlDecoder for identifying an entity's name I get a lot of not found errors in the batch chain i build."   Typically an individual's name will be associated with it by an `rdfs:label` property.    If you can  clarify what you're trying to do a bit, it will be easier to help.  As an aside (and one which probably shouldn't affect the rest of your question), I notice that your links are to the 3.7 version of the ontology, but DBpedia's up to version 3.9 now.

Comment: Thank you for adding information.  I don't know what you mean in "If the last statement in the triple is not an attribute I'm creating a relationship between those elements." doesn't make sense.  A _statement_ is the same thing as a _triple_;  it's a 3-tuple of the form `subject predicate object`.  (Predicates are sometimes called properties.)

Comment: RDF is graph based representation.  Each triple (aka statement) is an edge in the graph. The subject of the statement is one node, the predicate is the label of an edge, and the object is the other node. There are two types of nodes in an RDF graph:  literals (e.g., `"299.00"@en`); and resources (e.g., `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism>`).  Each resource is either an IRI or a blank node.  Are you asking how you can distinguish IRIs from blank nodes and literals?

Comment: What do you mean by "Just stripping off the tags and extracting the word Autism doesn't seem to to the deal?"?

Comment: sorry, meant to say if theobject is another entity like "Aristotle hasmainInterestin Philosophy" im creating a relationship between Aristotle and Philosophy.However I think I'mdoing primarily the identification of URIs wrong. Tha's my main concern. Thanks for your patience, so far. Can you just state how you would uniquely identify Autism in this case as the data associated with it is spread among multiple datasets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "uniquely identify Autism in this case as the data associated with it is spread among multiple datasets".  In RDF, the IRI _is_ the unique identifier.  The identifier for the resource `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism` _is the IRI_ `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Autism`.  RDF uses URLs/URIs/IRIs as identifiers precisely _because_ they've already been designed as universal resource identifiers (URI = Universal Resource Identifier;  IRI = Internationalized Resource Identifier).

Comment: If you're processing this data with an RDF-aware library (as you should be;  trying to process RDF with text-processing tools is not a great idea; though you're much less likely to run into trouble using this serialization than you would be if you were working with RDF/XML), then the library shouldn't make it too hard to identify which things are IRIs.  If, for some reason, you _do_ have to work with it as text, the grammar is described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-testcases/#ntriples);  you want the production `uriref ::= '<' absoluteURI '>'`.  The absoluteURI is the identified you need.

Comment: are there any transformations (e.g. Unicode escaping) that i have to deal with?

Comment: I never worry about it, because I use RDF libraries that I trust to parse the file.  But if you're not, the grammar that I linked to describes the details: `absoluteURI ::= character+ with escapes as defined in section URI References`, and `character ::= [#x20-#x7E] /* US-ASCII space to decimal 126 */`.  The section on character escaping is [3.2 Strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-testcases/#ntrip_strings): "The characters outside the US-ASCII range and some other specific characters are made available by \-escape sequences as follows: …" You'll have to look at the spec for the details.

Comment: I suppose youre referring to JENA?

Comment: Personally I typically use Jena, but there are lots out there: Jena, Sesame, Redland/Raptor, rdflib, etc.  My point is just that RDF is a graph based format that uses IRIs as identifiers.  It's easier to work with it on its own terms rather than wrestling with its serializations.

Comment: Did you end up making any progress with this?

Comment: I'm kind of looking into my error still. As of now I'm using a custom method to extract the object subject entitynames- But I'm using the same method. Even potentially aggregating with the wrong entity names I should be consistent I thought. If I don't have a clear result I'm gonna annoy you with some github examples I guess :)